# Is the list of tags supposed to be slanted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just opened up my user page on TeX.SE, and lo-and-behold, my list of tags appears in an interesting layout. Is that supposed to happen? (Can anyone reproduce?)

OS: Scientific Linux

Browser: Firefox 3.6.11

[image]

Comment: Same for me. (The reputation stat for each tag is nice, but the slanting is not.)

Comment: Same for Firefox 3.6.12 under Windows Vista; looks strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this in the morning and talked to Jin about it. Apparently it's a known bug and will be fixed in the next deployment (which will be in a day or two, I believe).

Comment: Ah, thanks. .....

Comment: What @martin said. The change should be in tonight(EST). It was caused by a new element we introduced (Answer Vote count next to the tags in the summary column).